# I am not able to apply conditional layout to a particular user/group field but can do it manually for any user

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

Please refer to the images attached.[conditional layout 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqr5j.png)

[conditional layout 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SEjU.png)

The [User who is applying for leave] field is a user/group field which gets populated with the record creator by default. The problem is this layout only works when I manually select a user. Then the particular user selected can see the layout. The layout doesn't work when I select the field i.e. the user/group field. Is it that Archer is not able to capture the user from the field and therefore the layout is not visible to the user? I am not able to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field [User who is applying for leave] is autopopylated. From Archer standpoint it is a calculated field. Calculated fields are recalculated and saved when record is getting saved.

When Archer applies actions for conditional layout for new record the field [User who is applying for leave] is not populated yet, therefore Archer applies actions as if the field was empty even if you see it populated on the screen.

I suggest you to modify layout actions in a way that all users (or specific group) can see fields/sections when record is new, and after record was saved for the first time you can restrict security based on the value of the saved fields.

Comment: Thanks Stan. Does this also apply for a record permission field or other fields which work on saving the record?

Comment: Yes, this applies to all calculated fields, including record permissions (automatic, inherited and manual) and calculated cross-referenced.
You can see all calculated fields in the calculation order list in the Archer application itself (I don't remember the Tab name :) )